# How do I turn my gui python file that uses jpegs and mp3s into an exe and not run into any errors?

Tags: python, file, user-interface, exe

I have a python file that uses tkinter and pygame along with some jpegs and mp3s for a music player. everytime i run "pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole main.py -i icon.ico" the exe file get's created but this is what i see (couldn't upload an image to the reddit for some reason so i'll just paste the error box i get). Am i missing something? whatever helps. Thanks!

Failed to execute script "main" due to unhandled exception: couldn't open "mp_icon_inpngformat.png.": no such file or directory

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "main.py", line 38, in

File "tkinter_*init*_.py", line 4129, in **init**

File "tkinter_*init*_.py", line 4074, in **init**

_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "mp_icon_inpngformat.png.": no such file or directory

And all I get is a tiny window opened labeled "tk." Feel like crap putting all this effort into this program and it not being able to execute the way I want it to. Thanks again! I've been using in cmd (C:\Users\Haytham\Desktop\MusicPlayer>pyinstaller --noconsole -i icon.ico), the folder that has my python file (has the mp3s and jpegs),
and the spec script (

````
    a = Analysis(
        ['main.py'],
        pathex=[],
        binaries=[],
        datas=[('C:\Users\Haytham\Desktop\MusicPlayer\mp_icon_inpngformat.png', '.'     ('C:\Users\Haytham\Desktop\MusicPlayer\icon.ico', '.'),     ('C:\Users\Haytham\Desktop\MusicPlayer\beat.png','.'),    ('C:\Users\Haytham\Desktop\MusicPlayer\music_folder','music_folder')    ('C:\Users\Haytham\Desktop\MusicPlayer\pause_button.png','.'),    ('C:\Users\Haytham\Desktop\MusicPlayer\play_button.png','.'),    ('C:\Users\Haytham\Desktop\MusicPlayer\rewind_button.png','.'),    ('C:\Users\Haytham\Desktop\MusicPlayer\skip_button.png','.')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
```)

I've tried looking into https://www.pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files but no luck. I did what it said, editing the data tuple of the spec file but nothing's worked.
````